# Custom marker icon in Google maps pops up before animation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following code to add a marker to my map:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: '/pin.png',
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    draggable: false,
    title: trip_name,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

Everything works fine except the icon pops up for a split second before running the animation. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: What happens if you exclude the map parameter when defining the marker, and then set the map afterwards? In other words, does a delay in setting the marker map parameter fix the issues?

Comment: What version of google maps are you using? According to the changelog, this issue was fixed in v3.7 (I've observed it before myself, but it was a long time ago before the 3.7 release). Original bug description - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3608 Changelog - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was experiencing this same behavior and I found that further defining the custom icon helped fix this issue.

```
var image = {
    url: 'images/map_marker.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 30 pixels tall.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 30),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the image at 0,30.
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 30)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   icon: image,
   map: map,
   position: latlng,
   draggable: false,
   title: trip_name,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```